# php code to calculate the average

Tags: php, sql

I want to write a script in php that calculates the average of a number of figures from the database.

I have tried this:

```
$average = ("SELECT AVG(Price) AS PriceAverage FROM Products");
```

But when I echo this I get 0.

Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: Well, you are not even calling any databases with your code; Please provide whole code example

Comment: Could you please show a bit thicker snippet from your code? It is unclear where you execute the query and handle it's response. `$average = ("SELECT AVG(...");` is just assigning text (string) to a variable.

Comment: Make DB Call else you will not get anything. Kindly update the whole code if you already have made db calls

Comment: Are you using mysql_*, mysqli_* or PDO make your question clear. You are not calling query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not executing the query. Use the code below

```
$average = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(Price) AS PriceAverage FROM Products");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($average)){
echo $row['PriceAverage'];
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the database, you could try this:

```
$average = ("SELECT AVG(Price) AS PriceAverage FROM Products");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($average);

echo $result['PriceAverage'];
```

Comment: When I try this I get: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

Comment: Could you edit your question and supply some more code?